# Javascript Markup Language Parser

Tags: javascript, regex, text-parsing

I'm trying to build a custom markup language parser using Javascript.

*For example:-*

- `**bold**` ==> **bold**
- `__italics__` ==> *italics*

To display the parsed text, I'm trying to replace the special characters with
the html tags, and pass them to `label`'s `innerHTML`.

- `**bold**` ==> `<b>bold</b>`

My first approach was to just use the `replace` function, but that was not ideal, as it can only replace the starting tag, and not the ending tag.

Then I found a temporary solution with JS regex,

```js
const bold = /\*\*([A-z0-9]+)\*\*/gi
const italics = /\_\_([A-z0-9]+)\_\_/gi

const updateTextMessage = () => {
    let text = $('#textParser').val()
    text = text.replace(bold, '<b>$1</b>')
    text = text.replace(italics, '<i>$1</i>')
    $('#parsedText').html(text)
}
```

```css
body{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="parsedText">Parsed text will appear here</span>
 <textarea id="textParser" oninput="updateTextMessage()" type="text" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
```

But the problem with this code is when I give a sentence in between, it doesn't work;

`**This sentence should be bold**` ==> **This sentence should be bold**

This doesn't work.

I know it is the regex that's not allowing this to happen, and I also know a work around regex i.e. `/\*\*(.*)\*\*/gim`

but this also converts unwanted situations as well.

For example, I don't want these to be valid syntax.

`** hello**`

`** hello, this a sentence**`

(The difference is the the separation between the special character and the text. It's kind of similar to how the WhatsApp markup text works.)

How do I solve this issue with regex? I'm also interested in other methods as well.

Comment: There are plenty of npm packages for this. Any reason to build your own? don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: You have to work out all the nuances of the grammar of your domain-specific markup language.  For example, do you want to allow escaping of characters with backslashes?  What about nesting `__**x**__`?  How do you want to resolve `**__**__`?  What is the markdown for two bold asterisks?  Things like that all need to be worked out.  Once you have a grammar then you can parse it and transform it - or decide if the grammar is simple enough for a regular expression to handle.  It's not unreasonable to [find a markdown module](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=markdown) either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close! You just need to put in a few changes so that you guarantee that the first letter near the double `*` or `_` characters is not whitespace.

`const bold = /\*{2}([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9\s]+[A-Z0-9])\*{2}/gi`
This breaks down into:

1. Check for two `*`
2. Check that the first character is alphanumeric.
3. Check that there are a series of alphanumeric or space characters.
4. Check that this is followed by an alphanumeric.
5. Finally, check that this ends with two `*`.

```js
const bold = /\*{2}([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\s]+[A-Za-z0-9])\*{2}/gi
const italics = /_{2}([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\s]+[A-Za-z0-9])_{2}/gi

const updateTextMessage = () => {
  let text = $('#textParser').val()
  text = text.replace(bold, '<b>$1</b>')
  text = text.replace(italics, '<i>$1</i>')
  $('#parsedText').html(text)
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="parsedText">Parsed text will appear here</span>
<textarea id="textParser" oninput="updateTextMessage()" type="text" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
```

Comment: [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for catching that but your adjustment did not produce correct results for lowercase letters (e.g. `**this sentence should be bold**`). Adjusted to fix that.